# How do I use Unicode characters in a tkinter app?

Tags: python, unicode, tkinter

I'm trying to make a magic trick game and I need playing cards to be displayed. My idea was to use the Unicode playing cards (U+1F0A0..U+1F0FF) but I don't know how to use them in a python program.

Comment: I assume it would be done the same way as displaying any other kinds of characters.

Comment: you can try `print('\u1F0FF')` but you need font which have correct char to display it.  Many fonts have other `card suits` chars like `print('A \u2660')` - `A ♠` (maybe you can see correctly "Ace Spade"): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode

Answer (score 0):

The normal way would be to use a Unicode literal.

2.x:

```
>>> print u'\U0001f0a5'
```

3.x:

```
>>> print('\U0001f0a5')
```

**HOWEVER.** Tkinter does not support text with characters in the [SMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane) and so will not work with said characters. You will need to use a different toolkit if you want to use them.

Comment: What do you mean by toolkit, and what ones should I use?